# how to show contents of Div based on options in a list angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

"Facing difficulties to show div contents dynamically"
Scenario:- I'm having 3 items in my list example {*Menu1 *Menu2 * Menu3 }
and I have 3 separate  div contents for each of this menu items..

Requirement :- By default menu1 should be displayed. 
and by clicking on menu2 the content of (menu1,menu3) should be hidden and menu 2 content should be displayed.

How  will I be able to do this angular 2 ?

Sharing my sample code and plucker..

## home.component.html

```
<div class="item-list>
 <div><li (click)="Menu2==false && Menu3==false;">Menu1</li></div>
 <div><li (click)="Menu1==false && Menu3==false;">Menu2</li></iv>
 <div><li (click)="Menu2==false && Menu1==false;">Menu3</li></div>
<div>

<div class="information">
 <div *ngIf="Menu1==true && Menu2==false && Menu3==false  ">Menu1 contents goes here</div>
 <div *ngIf="Menu2==true && Menu1==false && Menu3==false ">Menu2 contents goes here</div>
 <div *ngIf="Menu3==true  && Menu2==false && Menu1==false ">Menu3 contents goes here</div>
</div>
```

## home.ts

```
export class HomePage {


  private Menu1:boolean=true;
  private Menu2:boolean=false;
  private Menu3:boolean=false;
}
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TBaIzDA9l10XB47ng8EC?p=preview)

Comment: the plunker is the default one. fix it please

Comment: sorry i made a mistake i changing it.. @Korte

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/TBaIzDA9l10XB47ng8EC?p=preview @Korte   --- plz help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Component:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  // Declare the tag name in index.html to where the component attaches
  selector: 'hello-world',

  // Location of the template for this component
  templateUrl: 'src/hello_world.html'
})

export class HelloWorld {
  private home: boolean = true;
  private about: boolean = false;
  private contact: boolean = false;

  showMenu(menuName: string) {
    let menus = ['home', 'about', 'contact'];
    menus.splice(menus.indexOf(menuName), 1);
    for (const menu of menus) {
      this[menu] = false;
    };
    this[menuName] = true;
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="item-list">
    <div>
        <li (click)="showMenu('home')">home</li>
    </div>
    <div>
        <li (click)="showMenu('about')">about</li>
    </div>
    <div>
        <li (click)="showMenu('contact')">contact</li>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="information">
    <div *ngIf="home">home</div>
    <div *ngIf="about">about</div>
    <div *ngIf="contact">contact</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if the menu names be like (home, alert, settings ) it will only work for "Menu" please give me other solution @Korte

Answer (score 1):

I assume the first list is the menu selector, in which case

Where you have (click)="Menu2==false">, that is a comparison, you are not setting Menu2's value.

The following will do what you want:

```
<ul>
  <li (click)="Menu2=false; Menu3=false; Menu1=true">Menu1</li>
  <li (click)="Menu1=false; Menu3=false; Menu2=true">Menu2</li>
  <li (click)="Menu2=false; Menu1=false; Menu3=true">Menu3</li>
</ul>

<div *ngIf="Menu1 && !Menu2 && !Menu3">1</div>
<div *ngIf="Menu2 && !Menu1 && !Menu3">2</div>
<div *ngIf="Menu3 && !Menu1 && !Menu2">3</div>
```

Also, I don't think you need the 'divs' around your LI's